# Micrometer StackdriverMeterRegistry only publishes custom metrics to GCP Monitoring, not automatic instrumentation metrics?

Tags: quarkus, google-cloud-stackdriver, micrometer, google-cloud-monitoring

I have this example https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer (micrometer quickstart directory) running which uses Quarkus and Micrometer together. The example uses Prometheus as the MeterRegistry but I changed it to use the StackdriverMeterRegistry in hopes the same auto instrumentation that shows up in Prometheus would show up in Google Cloud Monitoring.

However, I only see the custom metrics I made appear into Google Cloud Monitoring, and not the auto instrumentation provided by micrometer.

I am unsure if I should think that this is just an issue with the Micrometer StackdriverMeterRegistry library itself or if I am doing something wrong. Any guidance is appreciated.

Code changes:

```java
        // Update the constructor to create the gauge
    ExampleResource(MeterRegistry registry) {
        /* Code for micrometer */
        StackdriverConfig stackdriverConfig = new StackdriverConfig() {
            @Override
            public String projectId() {
                return "projectId";
            }

            @Override
            public String get(String key) {
                return null;
            }
        };
        this.registry = StackdriverMeterRegistry.builder(stackdriverConfig).build();
        registry.config().commonTags("application", "projectId");
        registry.gaugeCollectionSize("example.list.size", Tags.empty(), list);
    }
```

Added to pom.xml

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-stackdriver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: All metrics gathered via micrometer using the stackdriver meter registry will appear as custom metrics (as in this section: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics). The publication/push mechanism is identical for all metrics collected by micrometer (regardless of how the meters were created).

Comment: As mentioned in the Micrometer guide, I would also try using the quarkiverse extension for stackdriver support: io.quarkiverse.micrometer.registry:quarkus-micrometer-registry-stackdriver .. there is a 1.x branch if you're using Quarkus 1.x, and a 2.x branch for Quarkus 2.x. Releases are in maven central

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering and speaking directly with the Micrometer team I found out the issue. The documentation is a bit confusing but I had imported the StackDriver extension wrong and the default registry being used for the quarkus project was getting all the auto instrumentation but not the StackDriver one. So this default registry needed to be changed to the StackDriver one.

I have uploaded a basic example of using Quarkus StackDriver and Micrometer together using the basic example found on the Micrometer Quarkus documentation page.

https://github.com/jayleenli/quarkus-micrometer-stackdriver-quickstart

The changes:

Add to pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkiverse.micrometer.registry</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer-registry-stackdriver</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then add some Quarkus properties, I used application.properties but there are other ways you can do this.

application.properties

```
quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.enabled=true
quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.default-registry=true
quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.project-id=fake-id
quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.publish=true
quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.resource-type=global
quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.step=1m
```

In main class

```
@Path("/")
public class ExampleResource {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.enabled")
    boolean enabled;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.default-registry")
    boolean export;
    @ConfigProperty(name="quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.project-id")
    String projectId;
    @ConfigProperty(name="quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.publish")
    boolean publish;
    @ConfigProperty(name="quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.resource-type")
    String resourceType;
    @ConfigProperty(name="quarkus.micrometer.export.stackdriver.step")
    String step;
```